# How do I get text from an text input using a button?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make it so the buttons function returns whatever is in the entry boxes when it is pressed. I know how to do it without using a .kv file but I’d rather use one as it is nicer.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    def get_input(self):
        pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        size: "100", "40"
        pos:  root.width / 2 - 50, root.height / 2 - 42
        on_press: root.get_input()
    TextInput:
        size: "250", "30"
        id: my_text
        multiline: False
        pos:  root.width / 2 - 125, root.height / 2 + 32
    TextInput:
        size: "250", "30"
        multiline: False
        pos:  root.width / 2 - 125, root.height / 2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution is always to add an id (just like you did) to the TextField in the .kv file:

```
TextInput:
        id: my_text
        size: "250", "30"
        multiline: False
        pos:  root.width / 2 - 125, root.height / 2 + 32
```

and then the text written in it can be accessed in this way:

```
def get_input(self):
    person = self.ids['my_text'].text # or self.ids.my_text.text
```